# React JS Router changes props of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am stuck at a combination of SSR and CSR.

[image: App.js]

I am passing grid-data(from php) to the Grid component.
The component looks like this: 
[image: Component-Grid-Pre]

If i click the "add"-button, it will add a new row to the table.
When i click on the "table"-link, the component changes to table.
When i click on the "grid"-link, to get back to the grid component, it keeps the new addet rows.

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       console.log(props);
       this.state = {
           clicked: false,
           grid: props.grid
       };

       console.log(this.state);

       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
       this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);

   }

   handleButton() {
       fetch('/react/add')
           .then(data => {
               return data.json()
           })
           .then(json => {
               let grid = this.state.grid;
               grid.data = [...grid.data, ...JSON.parse(json)];
               this.setState({
                   grid: grid
               });
           });
   }
```

The console.log is showing the props with the new addet rows from state.
How is this even possible?

**Edit:**
Take a look at: [streamable.com/ks8wf](http://streamable.com/ks8wf) The Grid Component is filled with props. The table Component isn't. If i change the url to table, the grid isn't resetted. If i change from table to grid and back, the table component is resetted

Kind regards

Comment: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: Sadly, this is not, what i am looking for. My problem is, that the props are changed, not the state

Comment: did you take a look at `componentDidUpdate()` ?

Comment: This did not work either.. Take a look at: https://streamable.com/ks8wf

The Grid Component is filled with props. The table Component isn't. If i change the url to table, the grid isn't resetted. If i change from table to grid and back, the table component is resetted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  handleButton() {
       fetch('/react/add')
           .then(data => {
               return data.json()
           })
           .then(json => {
           // Now the grid is new object
               let grid = {
               ...this.state.grid,
               data : [...grid.data, ...JSON.parse(json)]
               };
               this.setState({
                   grid: grid
               });
           });
   }
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :) Could you please explain, why this solution works? You said its a new object, but i don't really get, why my solution fails here..

Comment: the reason is because when you do something like 
"grid.data = [...grid.data, ...JSON.parse(json)];" 
you change the data of the grid without change the grid-object 
and now your grid-object  has more rows and when you go back to the grid page you still have the same object (with more rows), 

but if you use the grid-object like immutable-object  
by write "grid = { ...grid, data: [...grid.data, ...JSON.parse(json)] }, 
then you not change the props.grid but you create new object, 
and when you go back to the grid-page you have the same object that you send in the first time

Comment: look at 
https://benmccormick.org/2016/06/04/what-are-mutable-and-immutable-data-structures-2
and at https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/all-about-immutable-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript#immutable-object-operations

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i get it :)